# Indescript LetsEncript Certificate Generating Error

Tags: lets-encrypt, roots-sage, roots-toolkit

I have built a site with Roots' Trellis. But I forgot to enable SSL. So I changed the setting in `group_vars/production/wordpress_sites.yml` and re-provisioned but I'm getting this error.

```
TASK [letsencrypt : Generate the certificates] *****************************************************************
System info:
  Ansible 2.4.0.0; Darwin
  Trellis at "Fix `raw_vars` functionality for Ansible 2.4.1"
---------------------------------------------------
non-zero return code
fatal: [gordoncowie.com]: FAILED! => {"changed": false, "cmd": ["./renew-certs.py"], "delta": "0:00:00.918804", "end": "2018-07-16 20:00:38.681459", "failed": true, "rc": 1, "start": "2018-07-16 20:00:37.762655", "stderr": "", "stderr_lines": [], "stdout": "Generating certificate for gordoncowie.com\nError while generating certificate for gordoncowie.com\nTraceback (most recent call last):\n  File \"/usr/local/letsencrypt/acme_tiny.py\", line 198, in <module>\n    main(sys.argv[1:])\n  File \"/usr/local/letsencrypt/acme_tiny.py\", line 194, in main\n    signed_crt = get_crt(args.account_key, args.csr, args.acme_dir, log=LOGGER, CA=args.ca)\n  File \"/usr/local/letsencrypt/acme_tiny.py\", line 123, in get_crt\n    wellknown_path, wellknown_url))\nValueError: Wrote file to /srv/www/letsencrypt/VCyNAoWOu0lf4gTqJStnqfgPzcoaHRBuF5wZoJ_RpAA, but couldn't download http://www.gordoncowie.com/.well-known/acme-challenge/VCyNAoWOu0lf4gTqJStnqfgPzcoaHRBuF5wZoJ_RpAA", "stdout_lines": ["Generating certificate for gordoncowie.com", "Error while generating certificate for gordoncowie.com", "Traceback (most recent call last):", "  File \"/usr/local/letsencrypt/acme_tiny.py\", line 198, in <module>", "    main(sys.argv[1:])", "  File \"/usr/local/letsencrypt/acme_tiny.py\", line 194, in main", "    signed_crt = get_crt(args.account_key, args.csr, args.acme_dir, log=LOGGER, CA=args.ca)", "  File \"/usr/local/letsencrypt/acme_tiny.py\", line 123, in get_crt", "    wellknown_path, wellknown_url))", "ValueError: Wrote file to /srv/www/letsencrypt/VCyNAoWOu0lf4gTqJStnqfgPzcoaHRBuF5wZoJ_RpAA, but couldn't download http://www.gordoncowie.com/.well-known/acme-challenge/VCyNAoWOu0lf4gTqJStnqfgPzcoaHRBuF5wZoJ_RpAA"]}
```

To me, this seems completely indescript. Google searches produce basically no relevant results. Can anyone explain what this error means exactly?